# Javascript function not being recognized : Uncaught ReferenceError: change is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this basic Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <button type="button" onclick="change()">Try it</button>
         <script scr="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this basic Javascript file:

```
function change(){

   alert("asdfasdfa");

}
```

Both files are saved in the exact same location on my local disk.  However when I open the Html file in Chrome I get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: change is not defined

I have tested the script inline and that works fine, just not in an external file.  I have searched this issue and so far none of the 'solutions' I have found seem to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's `src` for source, not `scr`

Comment: Oh dear, that's embarrassing. Serves me right for using a text editor.

Comment: it happens @paj7777 :), we're here to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Typo:** Change `scr` to `src`:

```
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your markup that means `test.js` is never loaded.

You have a typo in the script tag. The attribute `src` is written `scr` in your example.